# Can I force pip to install a package even with a version conflict?

Tags: python, pip

During an installation, pip is throwing an error due to version conflicts

```bash
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement XXX==1.2.1
```

This is due to a package made by the company for witch I work ( not open source work ).
The reason for witch it is blocking is because it is locked in python version 3.6 and I am attempting to use python 3.9

Is it possible or not to ask pip to force install a package even though it was not built / tested for this specific version of python ?

To be clear, I am fully aware that this is normally ***not a good idea***. I however have little alternatives as the team that manages that specific package no longer exists. It is a dependency we are attempting to remove but until we can, we need to use it

Can I ask pip to use the latest version of the package even though it may break ? I'll add that there are no other package conflicts, just this one with python version so I should - in theory - be the only issue

Comment: if you have access to the source code then the workaround is to generate the package locally: [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391438/manually-installing-python-package). personally I would clone the repo, runs some tests to fix any syntax changes (can be done with [pyupgrade](https://github.com/asottile/pyupgrade)), then run `pip install .` while in my virtual env and the root dir containing your setup.py or pyproject.toml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it myself yet, but according to the documentation, pip install has the following argument that may help to bypass it:

```
--ignore-requires-python
Ignore the Requires-Python information.
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-ignore-requires-python